# Combine multiple rows and columns data in DataSet

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, datatable, dataset

I have a DataSet like below :

[image]

Where B1,B2 C1,C2 and C3 are the Column names. G1,G2,S1 and T1 are the first Row elements of my Data Set.

Now i want to combine Similar Columns/ROws in to Group .
Example : Columns B1, B2 and B3 combines to a single group B,
Rows : G1 and G2 Combines together to form a single row G.
Below is the O/P DataSet i need.

[image]

I have tried to use Dictionaries and DataSet Loops using but cant get this O/P .

Can anyone help me out with this.

Comment: Are the number of columns named `B` static?

Comment: The Number of Columns may vary with B like B1, B2, B3 and B4.. so on

Comment: Those statements conflict; are they static or do they vary? They can't be both.

Comment: They will Vary..@Larnu

Comment: What SQL Server version?

Comment: I am using SQL 2014

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This having to be dynamic adds a huge amount of complexity to this solution. As you haven't responded to the version question, I have not used `STRING_AGG`, however, if you are using SQL Server 2017+ you can simplify the query to use it.

Firstly, some sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE dbo.Matrix ([Data] char(2),
                         B1 tinyint,
                         B2 tinyint,
                         C1 tinyint,
                         C2 tinyint,
                         C3 tinyint)

INSERT INTO dbo.Matrix ([Data],
                        B1,
                        B2,
                        C1,
                        C2,
                        C3)
VALUES('G1',1,1,2,2,4),
      ('G2',1,1,1,1,1),
      ('S1',2,1,2,1,1),
      ('T1',1,3,2,2,3);
GO
```

Now, if this wasn't dynamic, you could use a a Cross tab to pivot the data into groups, like this:

```sql
SELECT LEFT(M.[Data],1) AS [Data],
       SUM(CASE V.Col WHEN 'B' THEN V.ColVal END) AS B,
       SUM(CASE V.Col WHEN 'C' THEN V.ColVal END) AS C
FROM dbo.Matrix M
     CROSS APPLY(VALUES('B',M.B1),
                       ('B',M.B2),
                       ('C',M.C1),
                       ('C',M.C2),
                       ('C',M.C3))V(Col,ColVal)
GROUP BY LEFT(M.[Data],1);
```

Unfortunately, as it *is* dynamic then we need dynamic SQL. Honestly, this isn't beginning stuff, and I'm not here to support this SQL; it's up to you to understand it, maintain it, support it, and (because it *is* dynamic SQL) keep it **secure**. I'm happy to answer some questions on *how* it works, but for someone that doesn't knowe SQL well this is a steep learning curve:

```sql
DECLARE @SQL nvarchar(MAX);

SET @SQL = N'SELECT LEFT(M.[Data],1) AS [Data],' + NCHAR(13) + NCHAR(10) +
           STUFF((SELECT N',' + NCHAR(13) + NCHAR(10) +
                         N'       SUM(CASE V.Col WHEN N' + QUOTENAME(LEFT(C.COLUMN_NAME,1),'''') + N' THEN V.ColVal END) AS ' + QUOTENAME(LEFT(C.COLUMN_NAME,1))
                  FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS C
                  WHERE C.TABLE_SCHEMA = N'dbo'
                    AND C.TABLE_NAME = N'Matrix'
                    AND C.COLUMN_NAME != N'Data' --Assumes that all other columns are applicable
                  GROUP BY LEFT(C.COLUMN_NAME,1)
                  ORDER BY LEFT(C.COLUMN_NAME,1)
                  FOR XML PATH(N''),TYPE).value('.','nvarchar(MAX)'),1,3,N'') + NCHAR(13) + NCHAR(10) +
          N'FROM dbo.Matrix M' + NCHAR(13) + NCHAR(10) +
          N'     CROSS APPLY(VALUES' + STUFF((SELECT ',' + NCHAR(13) + NCHAR(10) +
                                                     N'                       (N' + QUOTENAME(LEFT(C.COLUMN_NAME,1),'''') + N',M.' + QUOTENAME(C.COLUMN_NAME) + N')'
                                              FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS C
                                              WHERE C.TABLE_SCHEMA = N'dbo'
                                                AND C.TABLE_NAME = N'Matrix'
                                                AND C.COLUMN_NAME != N'Data' --Assumes that all other columns are applicable
                                              ORDER BY C.COLUMN_NAME
                                              FOR XML PATH(N''),TYPE).value('.','nvarchar(MAX)'),1,26,N'') + N')V(Col,ColVal)' + NCHAR(13) + NCHAR(10) +
         N'GROUP BY LEFT(M.[Data],1)' + NCHAR(13) + NCHAR(10) +
         N'ORDER BY LEFT(M.[Data],1);';

PRINT @SQL; --Your debugging best friend.

EXEC sp_executesql @SQL;
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=b9d7185b13e90ea662ee6b7b0221c5f9)

Answer (score 0):

You can apply below logic to get desired output from SQL Server:

```
create table T_DataSet
(
    Data varchar(50),
    B1 int,
    B2 int,
    C1 int,
    C2 int,
    C3 int
)

INSERT INTO T_DataSet ([Data],B1,B2,C1,C2,C3)
VALUES('G1',1,1,2,2,4),
      ('G2',1,1,1,1,1),
      ('S1',2,1,2,1,1),
      ('T1',1,3,2,2,3);


    
DECLARE @QUERY VARCHAR(MAX)='' 
DECLARE @Columns VARCHAR(MAX)=''


;with tbl_COLUMN_NAME (COLUMN_NAME) AS
(
    select name as COLUMN_NAME from sys.all_columns
    where object_id = (select object_id from sys.tables where name = 'T_DataSet')
    and name <> 'Data'
)

SELECT 
    @Columns = ISNULL(@Columns +',', '') + T.COLUMN_NAME
FROM 
( 
    select 
        COLUMN_NAME = 'SUM(' + 
            (select SUBSTRING( 
                    ( 
                            SELECT '+'+ COLUMN_NAME
                                FROM tbl_COLUMN_NAME
                                where LEFT(COLUMN_NAME,1) = LEFT(inner_C1.COLUMN_NAME,1)
                                FOR XML PATH('') 
             
                    ), 2 , 9999))
             + ') AS ' + LEFT(COLUMN_NAME,1)

    from tbl_COLUMN_NAME as inner_C1
    Group by LEFT(COLUMN_NAME,1)
    
)T


set @QUERY = 'select LEFT([Data],1) as Data ' + @Columns + '
    From T_DataSet
    Group by LEFT([Data],1)';

PRINT @QUERY
EXEC(@QUERY)
```